# metro menu using viewport3D how placing and resize items

Tags: c#, 3d, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps

I'm Trying create a menu like **windows 8 start menu (metro)**

its not hard to create buttons (i mean those special buttons that you all saw in metro style with image and description text) and do some animation for them like when mouse over the text change and show full description . i create those was not hard but ...

if you see win 8 start menu carefully you will see after button click there is a 3DRotation animation that rotate the button around Y axis and scale it to big (scale animation). the button come front and full screen then the page load and page element fade in page.

after 1 day search i understand i must use 3d working and i cant do that with 2d animation and transform.

now i create a viewport3D and i place my visual in that (4 buttons (UserControl)) then after click it rotation animation work .I using Viewport2DVisual3D for show my button in 3d viewport3D.

**problem is here :**

**1-** How can i resize my element to full screen of window (i scale it but it is not exact full screen and other element still are in back of this big one and if the user resize the window scale fail !)

**2-** after doing animation how can i remove other menu button (like close and minimize) from window .(i have a grid that has viewport3D and two button close and minimize in it after scale the button they are still there (i must set those 2 button in viewport3D too **?** because i dont need 3d effect for them))

**3-** when you maximize the window 3d element miss the real place how can i do like grid placing in viewport3D.(dont forget i cant put my button in grid because i need animation the visual then if i place them in grid visual will be whole grid , all grid will get animation)

I'm Using wpf in VS2010 and target pc with xp and 7 windows **;**

Answer (score 0):

in viewport3d, there are attributes like scalex,scaley and scalez. you can give scaling for each axis, also i thinking , you have to adjus fov , nearplane distance. when scaling.

please refer this link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/642253a6-e7a5-4ce2-bc08-e91f2634605b/disable-autoresize-autoscale-in-viewport3d?forum=wpf